# Google Speech-To-Text engine returns RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, google-speech-to-text-api

We have setup Google Speech-To-Text as a service, all the instances of our servers use the same Google cloud account for Speech-To-Text service.

However, one of the instances is constantly getting reply "**RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)**" whenever it tries to activate the Speech-To-Text service. Looking in the service quota in Google Cloud console I can see that we are very far from reaching the limits.

I didn't find anyway to get info why this instance fails to activate the speech-to-text service (while other servers instances are working just fine), I also didn't find in Google Cloud service anyway to see logs that show failed access to the speech-to-text service I set up.

Any idea how I can find and correct this issue?

Comment: The audio length should be ~1 minute when performing synchronous speech recognition requests/ ~480 minutes when performing asynchronous speech recognition requests/ ~5 minutes when performing streaming speech recognition requests and audio longer than ~1 minute must use the URI field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage. If you attempt to process content in excess of this limit will produce an error which is why you're getting the "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED" error message.

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content) for more information about content limits in Cloud Speech-to-Text and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have posted the comments as an answer. If my answer addressed your question, consider up-voting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 1):

The audio length should be

- ~1 minute when performing synchronous speech recognition requests
- ~480 minutes when performing asynchronous speech recognition requests
- ~5 minutes when performing streaming speech recognition requests

And audio longer than ~1 minute must use the URI field to reference an audio file in Google Cloud Storage.

If you attempt to process content in excess of this [limit](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content) will produce an error, which is why you're getting the `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` error message.